# Issue in Wildfly for Jacorb

Tags: jboss, wildfly, corba, iiop, jacorb

just i want to use some my own implementation of jacorb in wildfly 13 and also i am using iiop open jdk in wildfly 13 for that. An error is coming when i start my server, by this error i am not able to run the application successfully.

Error is: 
[javax.enterprise.resource.corba.*CORBA*.rpc.transport] (SelectorThread) "IOP00710304: (INTERNAL) Worker thread Thread[p: default-threadpool; w: Idle,5,ORB ThreadGroup 2] has been created with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.VisionWeb.war" from Service Module Loader": org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 304  completed: No.

please let me know the best solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be related but starting from WildFly 9, JacORB is no longer used
http://wildfly.org/news/2015/07/02/WildFly9-Final-Released/#_switched_to_the_openjdk_orb